# "If" statement not returning correct information.

Tags: c++

```
char capSentStart(char paragraph[], char newParagraph[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 301; ++i)
    {   
        if(paragraph[i] == '.' && paragraph[i + 1] == ' ')
        {   
            newParagraph[i] = '.';
            newParagraph[i + 1] = ' ';
            newParagraph[i + 2] = ' ';
            newParagraph[i + 3] = toupper(paragraph[i + 2]);
            ++i;
        }   
        else
        {   
            newParagraph[i] = paragraph[i];
        }   
    }   
}
```

If you input say the "paragraph" Dude. dude. dude. dude.
and then cout << newParagraph; 
it prints the same paragraph with nothing changed.

Comment: Be careful with the indexes and the bounds..

Comment: Learn to use debugger, it will help you finding solutions to issues like this.

Comment: It does change `newParagraph` when it encounters a period. But you need think about about what it does in the *following* iterations of the loop as well.

Comment: The desire to know what this is *trying* to do is almost overwhelming. I think you would be well-served with *two* index variables.

Comment: @WhozCraig:: ROFL literally :-D

Answer (score 2):

As per your code, if the current character is `"."`, then you are doing what you want inside the `if condition`. Consider the cases, when the current character is not `"."`. You are merely copying the original paragraph which replaces the previous characters in the `newParagraph`.

Say input: `Dude. dude.`

When the current character is the first `.`, the `newParagraph` at the end of iteration is:

```
Dude. D___
```

where `_` indicates the characters yet to be filled.

But, in the next four iterations, we don't find a `.`. So, you are copying the data from the `input` into the `newParagraph` thus over-writing the changes.

```
Dude. dude.
```

**EDIT:**

Your code is trying to convert the first character of every sentence to upper Case. Here is how it should be modified:

```
char capSentStart(char paragraph[], char newParagraph[])
{
    int new_paragraph_idx=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 301; ++i)
    {   
        if(paragraph[i] == '.' && paragraph[i + 1] == ' ')
        {   
            newParagraph[new_paragraph_idx++] = '.';
            newParagraph[new_paragraph_idx++] = ' ';
            newParagraph[new_paragraph_idx++] = ' ';
            newParagraph[new_paragraph_idx++] = toupper(paragraph[i + 2]);
            ++i;
        }   
        else
        {   
            newParagraph[new_paragraph_idx++] = paragraph[i];
        }   
    }   
}
```

Put a `new_ptr` which actually fills the `newParagraph` separately, thus preventing the over-writing. And also take care of the bounds of the strings. Otherwise you might end up with a [SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

Comment: Naming the integer index `new_ptr` is quite misleading, since it is not a pointer after all.

Answer (score 0):

In the True case of the if statement you are filling newParagraph but when you keep itterating you are overwriting them again in the false case of the if statement. You should have two itterating variables for Paragraph and new Paragraph.

In order to give you a more detailed answer you should tell us the expeced output.

Answer (score 0):

You are always writing based on the index `i`. Even if you write on higher indexes in `newParagraph`, then the follow iterations will overwrite what was done.

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
char capSentStart(char paragraph[], char newParagraph[])
{

    for(int i = 0,j = 0; i < 301; ++i,++j)
    {   
        if(paragraph[i] == '.' && paragraph[i + 1] == ' ')
        {   
            newParagraph[j] = '.';
            newParagraph[j + 1] = ' ';
            newParagraph[j + 2] = ' ';
            newParagraph[j + 3] = toupper(paragraph[i + 2]);
            j=j+3;
            i=i+2;
        }   
        else
        {   
            newParagraph[j] = paragraph[i];
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing the first iteration in `if(paragraph[i] == '.' && paragraph[i + 1] == ' ')`, gives:

```
          paragraph[i] = '.'
                    ^
   paragraph = "Dude. dude.  ..."
newParagraph = "Dude. D         "
```

After `++i` and the increment of i in the `for`loop, `i` moves to the following:

```
            paragraph[i] = 'd'
                      ^
   paragraph = "Dude. dude.  ..."
newParagraph = "Dude. D         "
```

But this time, the iteration executes the code in `else`.

```
else
{
    newParagraph[i] = paragraph[i];
}
```

This changes the `newParagraph[i]` which is `D` to `paragraph[i]`, which is `d`.

```
            paragraph[i] = 'd'
                      ^
   paragraph = "Dude. dude.  ..."
newParagraph = "Dude. d         "   //'D' is changed back to 'd'
```

Afterwards, `newParagraph` just get overwritten into `paragraph`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char capSentStart(char paragraph[], char newParagraph[])
{
    int index=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 301; ++i)
    {  
        index=i; 
        if(paragraph[i] == '.' && paragraph[i + 1] == ' ')
        {   
            newParagraph[i] = '.';
            newParagraph[i + 1] = ' ';
            newParagraph[i + 2] = ' ';
            newParagraph[i + 3] = toupper(paragraph[i + 2]);
            index=i+3;
       }   
       else
       {   
           newParagraph[i] = paragraph[i];
       } 
       i=index;
    }   
}
```